# How can I order data returned in an anonymous type?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
         return Ok(new
            {
                Answer = (string) null,
                Text = question.Text,
                Answers = question.Answers.Select((a, i) => new
                {
                    AnswerId = a.AnswerId,
                    AnswerUId = i + 1,
                    Correct = (bool?) null,
                    Response = (bool?) null,
                    Text = a.Text
                })
            });
```

How can I order the Answers returned by AnswerId ?

Comment: Does `.OrderBy(x => x.AnswerId)` do the trick? Either before or after should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
.OrderBy( z => z.AnswerId)
```

immediately after your Select statement.